# Custom tcrossprod function in R

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, cross-product

I am using the [tcrossprod](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/crossprod.html) function on a matrix in R. It does a cross product of my data and its transpose. i.e. data %*% t(data).

The problem is, I don't want the individual operations (between rows in data and columns in t(data)) to be multiplication operations. Is it possible to specify my own function in there so that the same algorithm is implemented but it does something else instead of multiplication.

I am achieving the same result now by looping through the matrices and performing the required operation but the looping makes this approach slow.

Here's what I am currently doing (but replacing the * operation with something else):

```
count<-nrow(data)
output<-sapply(1:count, function(x){
        sapply(1:count, function(y){
                sum((data[x,]+data[y,])*abs(data[x,]-data[y,]))
            })
    })
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what function you pan to use? Whether it is or can be vectorized can help us give you a fast-running solution.

Comment: That does not help. We want to know what *"something else"* looks like. Without it, the (slow) general answer is to do a double loop like you did.

Comment: thanks @flodel, added the desired operation.

Comment: I'm intrigued: can you give a little background as to the situation you're analyzing, i.e. how/why a cross-"function" operation on two matrices gives useful information?

Comment: I deleted my solution as it got slower than your initial code on very large matrices.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, the rows in the data matrix represent nodes in a graph and the output matrix is an adjacency matrix with the values being some measure of the edge weights. (I know there will be a fair bit of duplication here). That's why I need to consider, for each row, every other row in data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace one of your slow `sapply` loop with much faster matrix operations:

```
sapply(1:count, function(i, x) {
   colSums((x + x[, i]) * abs(x - x[, i]))} , x = t(data))
```

And to make that a tiny bit faster, replace `sapply` with `vapply`:

```
vapply(1:count, function(i, x) {
   colSums((x + x[, i]) * abs(x - x[, i]))} , numeric(count), x = t(data))
```

If this is still too slow for you, then most likely a Rcpp solution will do. Otherwise I do not see a base-only solution that would be significantly faster than this (I'd be glad to be proven wrong though.)